# R lookup values (multiple arguments) in dataset with multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following problem:

I have two datasets like that:

```
a <- data.frame(date = c("12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016"),
                company = c("ABBN VX EQUITY", "APL US EQUTIY", "PAY US EQUITY"))

b <- data.frame(date = c("07.01.2016", "08.01.2016", "09.01.2016", "10.01.2016", "11.01.2016", 12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016", "15.01.2016", "16.01.2016"),
                company = c("ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY"),
                return = c("10%", "15%", "3%", "8%", "12%", "3%", "10%", "4%", "9%", "22%"),
                date = c("07.01.2016", "08.01.2016", "09.01.2016", "10.01.2016", "11.01.2016", 12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016", "15.01.2016", "16.01.2016"),
                company = c("APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY"),
                return = c("11%", "5%", "19%", "4%", "8%", "10%", "7%", "3%", "9%", "11%"), 
                date = c("07.01.2016", "08.01.2016", "09.01.2016", "10.01.2016", "11.01.2016", 12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016", "15.01.2016", "16.01.2016"),
                company = c("PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY"),
                return = c("11%", "5%", "19%", "4%", "8%", "10%", "7%", "3%", "9%", "11%"))
```

Now I would like to match these dateframes in the manner, that the output is:

```
c <- data.frame(date = c("12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016"),
                company = c("ABBN VX EQUITY", "APL US EQUTIY", "PAY US EQUITY"),
                return = c("4%", "3%", "3%")
```

I tried with leftjoin from dyplr but that always gives me all the columns back with all the columns after the match of the two values (date and company) but I only want the columns returns for each pair.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't understand why the return values in data frame c is `"4%", "3%", "3%"`. Could you explain more?

Comment: each three column is for one company in `b`. @ycw but it has to be 3,4,3.

Comment: @Masoud I got an answer of `3, 7, 3`. Let's see how the OP thinks.

Comment: @ycw I meant to type `3, 7, 3`. 4 and 7 are close in the numpad. LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `a2` would be the final output. Notice that your example data frames contain typos. I would also suggest that do not turn your columns to factor. Please see the `Data Preparation` section to see how I construct the example data frame.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Clean data frame b
b2 <- b %>%
  select(-date.1, -date.2) %>%
  gather(Return_Group, Return, contains("return")) %>%
  gather(Company_Group, Company, contains("company")) %>%
  filter(sub("return", "", Return_Group) == sub("company", "", Company_Group)) %>%
  select(date, company = Company, return = Return)

# Apply left_join
a2 <- a %>%
  left_join(b2, by = c("date", "company"))
```

#### Data Preparation

```
a <- data.frame(date = c("12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016"),
                company = c("ABBN VX EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

b <- data.frame(date = c("07.01.2016", "08.01.2016", "09.01.2016", "10.01.2016", "11.01.2016", "12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016", "15.01.2016", "16.01.2016"),
                         company = c("ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY", "ABBN VX EQUITY"),
                         return = c("10%", "15%", "3%", "8%", "12%", "3%", "10%", "4%", "9%", "22%"),
                         date = c("07.01.2016", "08.01.2016", "09.01.2016", "10.01.2016", "11.01.2016", "12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016", "15.01.2016", "16.01.2016"),
                company = c("APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY", "APL US EQUITY"),
                return = c("11%", "5%", "19%", "4%", "8%", "10%", "7%", "3%", "9%", "11%"), 
                date = c("07.01.2016", "08.01.2016", "09.01.2016", "10.01.2016", "11.01.2016", "12.01.2016", "13.01.2016", "14.01.2016", "15.01.2016", "16.01.2016"),
                         company = c("PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY", "PAY US EQUITY"),
                         return = c("11%", "5%", "19%", "4%", "8%", "10%", "7%", "3%", "9%", "11%"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the responses. The output should be 3%, 7%, 3% of course. Sorry for the mistake. I'm not really familiar how to insert code into stackoverflow properly. I would have displayed the output as a table, but didn't manage to do so.